# Use Linux BIND DNS server for my Windows Active Directory 2008 R2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, bind

How can I use a Linux BIND DNS server for my Windows Sever 2008 R2 Active Directory?

We are trying to avoid having to use the Windows Sever 2008 Server as a Domain Controller at all.

We want to use Ubuntu Server with bind configuration as DNS for all our workstations as is it easy to upload new changes in gitlab/github and it will auto pull in /etc/bind/ folder and will auto restart bind9 service with cronjob script.

After this is setup, all that remains is to tell Windows Server R2 that Ubuntu is DNS Server now. Otherwise Domain Controller users login is very slow, unless I put Windows Domain Controller IP as a secondary DNS in IPV4 config in workstations. Which we don't want to do. We want to use Ubuntu Server with bind as primary DNS and Google as secondary 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Update: We have a load balancer which is also working as DHCP and we can tell what to assign to workstations connected to Ethernet ports. So assigning dns to workstations is not an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a Linux BIND DNS server for my Active Directory forest?](http://serverfault.com/questions/561449/how-can-i-use-a-linux-bind-dns-server-for-my-active-directory-forest)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is strongly dis-recommended (if that's English!) by Microsoft (and you're supporting Microsoft clients). Second, you'd have done that when you put in place your AD, as your domain controller would have skipped the creation of its own DNS. It's anyway possible to do it, if your BIND DNS is compatible.

If you're clients are slow to login, that's because you BIND DNS is not able to resolve your client queries, it replies with "I don't know that host", then your clients query to the secondary.

The easy way to do this would be:
- Your DC as a primary (I know you don't want / are not allowed; still, it's the recommendation).
- Your BIND DNS as secondary.
- Google DNS as a forwarder in your BIND DNS.

Difficult way, this oldie but goldie link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316373.aspx

Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not recommended at all... It is still valid answer even after the years...

## Slow login

This is because of waiting for the domain name resolving. Active directory is DNS based service and it is used for discovery of the nodes with proper roles... There is not direct relation between Active Directory, DHCP and other AD roles.

## use case for the Windows server...

### standalone server

In case you want just some service you don't need  to run AD services. In that case you don't need to take care about any of the related stuff like DHCP, DNS, etc. Negative part of this is authentication as all credentials will be just local.

In case you want to operate the server(s) in this mode it may have sense to think about some external maintenance tool to handle the local user's accounts - Identity management system...

For example [Midpoint](https://evolveum.com).

### Active Directory

In this role you can use the same credentials over the domain and in case you have more servers you not necessary have to handle the credentials per server... You case run all services on Windows servers or as you have mentioned you can limit what will be provided by the windows server :

- BIND as DNS server

With this role you need to have defined domain you want to use with AD in bind in advance and also you have to allow dynamic update from future AD's IP. At Windows domain doesn't offer TSIG feature you have to allow updates somply from the IP...
Then during installation you should use bind as DNS server and Windows system will find out that the domain exists and you can select to use external DNS for the AD records. Then Windows server will not act as DNS server at all... You have to allow dynamic updates from AD server as there is short TTL records updated by the server needed for the domain functionality - like location of the services...

But to have it working correctly once you will use AD - e.g. domain / AD membership you have to allow dynamic updates otherwise it will just not work as suppose.

- DHCP (e.g.) on linux server

DHCP server is optional service on Windows server so nothing will force to use it...

- AD member

You can also operate Active Directory Domain controller over some Samba installation.